# Get location.href by class

Tags: javascript, jquery, mediawiki

I'm using MediaWiki, and I can't use the tag `<script></script>`.

Have an method to I get the url (location.href) by class?

For example, I put the code location.href in the js file, and in the page I put:

`<div class="someclass"></div>`

And appear the url?

Comment: I'm very unsure as to what you're asking, `location.href` doesn't change accross a page.

Comment: Why is this tagged `javascript` and `jquery` if you're not allowed to use scripts?

Comment: @Aesthete I can't use the TAG script, but I can use the JS file. (name.js)

Comment: So how do you import your scripts into your page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a lot of "variables" available, this should print the current URL(without any scripts):

```
<div>{{canonicalurl:{{FULLPAGENAME}}}}</div>
```

http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Help:Magic_words